# Speeding up Pandas .apply function. Counting rows and doing operation with them

Tags: python, pandas, performance, apply

I have a huge database of migratory movements and I wrote some scripts to get useful info from it but it's really really slow. I'm not a professional coder as you will see, and I was wondering how to make this data gathering more efficient.

To start, the initial CSV database is structured as follows:

> 1 row = 1 person
>
> ```
>           Age       Sex      City_start      City_destination  ...
> ```
>
> Person 1
>
> Person 2
>
> .....

The final database structure:

> ```
>          Balance_2004    Balance_2005       ....
> ```
>
> City1
>
> City2
>
> ....

For calculating this Balance per city and year I created a function that filters the initial database to count how many rows have a specific city in city_destination (INs), how many rows in city_start (OUTs) and then a simple sum to calculate the balance as INs - OUTs:

```
 # idb = initial database
 # City1 = pre-existing in final database
 
 def get_balance(city, df):
    ins = idb.City_start[idb.City_start == City1].count()
    outs = idb.City_destination[idb.City_destination == City1].count()
    balance = ins - outs
    return balance
```

Then with this function I used pandas apply to populate the final database as:

```
# fdb = final database

fdb['Balance_2004'] = idb['City_start'].apply(get_balance, df=idb)
```

This works good, the ending result is what I need and I'm using in total 42 apply functions to get more specific data like balance per sex, per ages groups... but to give an idea of how slow this is, I started the script (with 42 functions) 45min ago and is still running.

Is there any way to do this in a less time-consuming way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How working my or another solution?

Answer (score 1):

I believe need aggregate by `cities` with `year`s with [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), then subtract by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) and if necessary convert to `integer`s:

```
idb = pd.DataFrame([("a", "Chicago", "Chicago", 2018),
                    ("b", "New York", "Chicago", 2018), 
                    ("c", "New York", "Chicago", 2017),
                    ("d", "Houston", "LA", 2018)], 
        columns=["Name", "City_start", "City_destination", 'year'])
print (idb) 
  Name City_start City_destination  year
0    a    Chicago          Chicago  2018
1    b   New York          Chicago  2018
2    c   New York          Chicago  2017
3    d    Houston               LA  2018


a1 = idb.groupby(["City_start", 'year']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
a2 = idb.groupby(["City_destination", 'year']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

idb = a1.sub(a2, fill_value=0).astype(int).add_prefix('Balance_')
print (idb)
year      Balance_2017  Balance_2018
Chicago             -1            -1
Houston              0             1
LA                   0            -1
New York             1             1
```

Answer (score 1):

It might make sense to do this calculation only once, by grouping by the cities:

```
def get_balance_all_cities(df):
    df_diff = pd.DataFrame([df.groupby(["City_start"])["Name"].count(),
                            df.groupby(["City_destination"])["Name"].count()]).T
    df_diff.columns = "start", "end"
    df_diff[df_diff.isna()] = 0
    return df_diff.start - df_diff.end
```

Here are some examples for how it works:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([("Person 1", "Chicago", "Chicago"), ("Person 2", "New York", "Chicago"), ("Person 3", "Houston", "New York")], columns=["Name", "City_start", "City_destination"])

>>> df
       Name City_start  City_destination
0  Person 1    Chicago           Chicago
1  Person 2   New York           Chicago
2  Person 3    Houston          New York

>>> ins = df.groupby(["City_start"])["Name"].count()
City_start
Chicago     1
Houston     1
New York    1
Name: Name, dtype: int64

>>> outs = df.groupby(["City_end"])["Name"].count()
City_destination
Chicago     2
New York    1
Name: Name, dtype: int64

>>> df_diff = pd.DataFrame([ins, outs]).T
>>> df_diff.columns = "start", "end"
>>> df_diff[df_diff.isna()] = 0
>>> balance = df_diff.start - df_diff.end
Chicago    -1.0
Houston     1.0
New York    0.0
dtype: float64
```

The work-around at the end is to deal with cities in where no-one lives during end or start but does live during the other time.